# Regression method for Poisson Process

Tags: survival, recurrent-events

I was searching regarding Poisson process and data lay out for recurrent events. After diving into heap of literature its better that I should ask to someone. What steps should we take to write parametric maximum likelihood for recurrent event for Poisson process for Weibull PH model when covariates are fixed. I know the general form i.e $L(\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^{m}  L_i(\theta) $ where 
$$L_i(\theta)= \prod_{j=1}^{n_i}\{\rho_o(t_{ij})\exp\left({x'_{i}(t_{ij})}\beta \right)\} \exp\big(-\int Y_i(s)\rho_o(s)\exp\left({x'_{i}(s)}\beta\right) ds\big)$$.

There is heap of literature I need clear description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you want to model recurrent events in calendar time, that would be the Poisson process formulation. If you want to use a Weibull model you simply need to use a Weibull baseline intensity, which is the same as the Weibull hazard, i.e.
$$
\rho_0(t) = b k t^{k-1}
$$
See the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) page for parametrizations. In R, you can use the `survreg` function in the `survival` package for this (keep in mind that that might use a different parametrization of the Weibull distribution).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. yes I did understand that but I am worrying about cumulative hazard part. Does this also follow weibul or Poisson distribution.  As likelihood can be decompose it to $L_1(\theta)L_2(\theta,\beta)$ where $L_1$ arise from the conditional distribution  of the event times given counts and $L_2$ arises from poisson distribution of the counts. please can you tell me that cumulative hazard is from poisson distribution or from weibull?

Comment: The cumulative hazard is in this case the expected number of events. The cumulative hazard in itself does not have a distribution, it is an expression of the distribution of the counts. Regardless of the rate used to model the Poisson process, the counts in any given window of time follow a Poisson distribution.